# Huawei hilink (E3372) web api delete-sms returned error 125003

Tags: bash, curl

I'm trying to do SMS things with the API read/send is ok, but when it comes to deleting part it always return error 125005, which is I believed related to session and token.

It's very limited information on internets
about example on how to used the API.

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash 

MODEM_IP="192.168.9.1" 
curl -s -X GET "http://$MODEM_IP/api/webserver/SesTokInfo" > ses_tok.xml
COOKIE=`grep "SessionID=""ses_tok.xml | cut -b 10-147`
TOKEN=`grep "TokInfo" ses_tok.xml | cut -b 10-41` 

curl -s -X POST "http://$MODEM_IP/api/sms/sms-list" -H "Cookie: $COOKIE" -H "__RequestVerificationToken: $TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -d "<request><PageIndex>1</PageIndex><ReadCount>20</ReadCount><BoxType>1</BoxType><SortType>0</SortType><Ascending>0</Ascending><UnreadPreferred>1</UnreadPreferred></request>" > modem_status.xml

#cat modem_status.xml

#read index
readarray -t array_index <<< "$(xmlstarlet sel -t -m "//Index" -v . -n modem_status.xml)"

rm -f result_status.xml
touch result_status.xml

for ((i=0; i<${#array_index[@]}; i++ ))
do
     index[$i]=$(printf ${array_index[$i]} | tr -d '\n\r ')
     #printf "${index[$i]} "
     printf "\n${index[$i]}\n" >> result_status.xml
     curl -s -X POST "http://$MODEM_IP/api/sms/delete-sms" -H "Cookie: $COOKIE" -H "__RequestVerificationToken: $TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -d "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><request><Index>${index[$i]}</Index></request>" >> result_status.xml
done

cat result_status.xml
```

Errors:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<error>
<code>125003</code>
<message></message>
</error>
```

Maybe, I missed something that I didn't notice before.

Comment: you must login first

Comment: @dopstar and leenoux:  What I noticed is `/api/webserver/SesTokInfo` returns a payload whether you're logged in or not. How do you actually know whether the SessionID is expired or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe too late but I had the same issue and maybe this helps also other users looking for it.

In my case the token/cookie already expired right before the delete command.
I don't think that it is a time component involved but more like the combination is only valid for one API call.

I get a new token/cookie right before the delete command and now it works for me. Hope this helps.

Cheers
Chris

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same error, in your case you ask for delete sms, I've asked for reboot. Modem should have verified connection based on token, saved in cookies to perform any action.

I've used 3 steps.

1) First is connection to e3372.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><request><dataswitch>1</dataswitch></request>
```

by **/api/dialup/mobile-dataswitch** path.

2) Second is getting token by **/api/webserver/SesTokInfo** path, and save in cookies.
python example attached.

```
 def _getTokens(self):
    """Get access tokens"""
    try:
        xml = self._getXml("/api/webserver/SesTokInfo")
    except (URLError, socket.timeout):
        return ("", "")
    else:
        return (xml.findtext("SesInfo", ""), xml.findtext("TokInfo", ""))

def _updateTokens(self):
    session, postToken = self._getTokens()
    self._opener.addheaders = [("__RequestVerificationToken", postToken),
                               ("Cookie", session)]
```

3) Reboot modem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><request><Control>1</Control></request>
```

by **/api/device/control** path.

Answer (score 1):

As this was the top result for `Huawei 125003` I'll add my findings when hitting this error.
On the B315s that I have the __RequestVerificationToken can only be used once.
Every POST request should have a response header of __RequestVerificationToken you can just take this value and use it for the next request. Just note that the response to **/api/user/login** will return a number of tokens that you can use, they are separated by the hash # symbol.

Also keep on top of your cookies, the SesInfo saved from **/api/webserver/SesTokInfo** will change once you've successfully logged in.

Comment: What I noticed is `/api/webserver/SesTokInfo` returns a payload whether you're logged in or not. How do you actually know whether the SessionID is expired or not?

Answer (score 0):

As of 2020 or so, not sure if python works exactly the same but curl and .net framework need the `SessionID` presented as a cookie and not a cookie in the header. Like the following, note the `-b` option in curl:

```
cmd_output=$(curl -s -X GET "http://192.168.8.1/api/webserver/SesTokInfo")

COOKIE=$(echo $cmd_output | cut -b 58-185)

TOKEN=$(echo $cmd_output | cut -b 205-236)

curl -s -X POST "http://192.168.8.1/api/sms/sms-list" **-b "SessionID=$COOKIE"** -H "__RequestVerificationToken: $TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -d "<request><PageIndex>1</PageIndex><ReadCount>10</ReadCount><BoxType>1</BoxType><SortType>0</SortType><Ascending>0</Ascending><UnreadPreferred>1</UnreadPreferred></request>"
```